# Will splitting one large MySQL query into multiple smaller queries help mitigate table locking / force a script to "yield" to other PHP scripts?

Tags: php, mysql, locking, left-join

We have a large number of tables in our company's `MySQL` database, each representing different products (and/or history/transactions for those products) plus a "main" table for parent establishments.  Almost all of these tables are using `MyISAM` (changing everything to `InnoDB` might help but it's not an option at the moment).

We have a "filter" tool in our backend for finding establishments that match certain criteria.  The results are printed in tabular format with all data available for that establishment (ID, name, which products they do/don't have, how many transactions, etc. etc.) and currently this is achieved with a very large `MySQL` statement with many `JOIN`s.

We had a situation last week where a particularly large filter was run during peak business hours and the resulting `READ LOCK`s on dependent tables (via the aforementioned `JOIN` statements) caused the entire database to stop responding for almost 30mins even though the filter in question only takes ~43s to run on it's own (locally, anyway).  Very bad.

While important, this filter tool is only used by a few people on the team and not by clients.  **The speed/performance of this filter tool is not critical nor the goal of this question.  I would prefer for this tool to "yield" to other apps that need access to these tables rather than force them to wait until the entire filter has finished.**

Which brings me to my question; **Will splitting one large query (with multiple `JOIN`s) into multiple smaller queries help mitigate table locking and force a script to "yield" to other, higher priority scripts that might need access to the same tables in between the smaller queries?**

*Disclaimer: I have reviewed so many other questions here on StackOverflow and on other sites via Google over the last week and they're all interested in speed.  That is not what I am asking.  If this is a duplicate I apologize and it can be locked, but please provide a link to it so that I may use it.  Thank you!*

EDIT:  I appreciate the comments thus far and the additional information/ideas they provide, though none have answered the question unfortunately.  I'm in a position at the company where I have control over the filter's code and that's it.  I cannot change the database engine, I cannot initiate replication or create data warehouses, and I'm already aware that `MyISAM` is the inferior choice for tables, but I don't have control over that.  Thank you.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I've already started doing this and have been working on it for the last several days but it's a long process I wont know whether or not it "works" until I push it to production which is why I'm asking.  (It's hard to answer a question like this with local testing and I can't find a straight answer online).

Comment: Splitting might help if each of those scripts runs quickly. How would you execute them...through a stored procedure? Or by multiple separate calls from a PHP application? That also assumes you can get the same accurate results back with such a split? we can't comment on that really. Of course, if the filter query is inefficient then optimising it ought to be an option you should consider, since it reduces the potential for overlapping queries.

Comment: Or, if you have the space / capacity, you could create  slave replica of the database, and read from that replica when running the filter, thus avoiding locking on the main database. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Using MyISAM is a huge liability. That database could be corrupted, irrecoverably, by a database crash. Usually updating is as easy as `ALTER TABLE`. That "one weird trick" might solve your locking issues as MyISAM is a **truly awful database engine**. You say switching isn't an option, but do you have a recovery plan for when this database inevitably tanks because of a bad crash?

Comment: The answer here is probably to create a "data warehouse" replica of your database and query off of that. Since you're using MyISAM this isn't easy. If you were using InnoDB then you could easily replicate it, or snapshot it using a variety of InnoDB-specific tools. With MyISAM you have very limited options. It's also a lot easier to tune InnoDB to work better under load, you can throw heaps of memory at it to improve performance, and other things simply not possible with MyISAM.

Comment: Once you set up replication (which will need some downtime), you could have the Replica(s) using InnoDB while the Primary still uses MyISAM.

Comment: Are the schemas (table definitions) for the different products different?

Comment: @RickJames The schemas are all different.  They were created by different employees over the course of over 10 years.  It's a mess but that's beyond my control.  I'm only able to alter the code for the filter itself.

Comment: @tadman I agree that InnoDB would be the superior choice and if we were creating new tables I would use them.  Unfortunately A) I don't have control over the database tables themselves and even if I did B) there are hundreds, maybe thousands of scripts that interact with these tables and the amount of testing required after changing each of them would not be a small feat.  Like I mentioned in other comments, I only have control over the filter code - not the tables it pulls from.  Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for attempting to answer the question directly.  I think a slave replica would is a wonderful idea and if this were a personal project or one I had more control over I would likely use something like that, but alas I only have control over the filter itself.  To answer your question, I would execute these queries through multiple calls in a PHP application (each one using the primary keys collects from the previous to narrow-down the scope of the results).  Also, yes, while I separate these intro smaller queries I'm individually optimizing them as much as possible.

Comment: By using "separate" queries, you are forgoing a lot of optimizations.

Comment: I'm just suggesting from experience even though switching to InnoDB may be non-trivial and exhausting, the cost of *not switching* is ongoing and will only compound over time. MyISAM just can't be tuned like InnoDB can. It will always perform badly in comparison. That your database hasn't tanked and eaten itself already is a small miracle.

Comment: @RickJames In theory I agree, but in practice it's more complicated than that.  Now that I've started the process, I've found that the filter actually runs faster on most queries as I'm able to intuitively know when certain `JOIN`s are or are not needed that I wouldn't have been able to know/do with one large query.  That being said, each of the smaller queries are being heavily optimized and the overall speed is irrelevant to the end-goal (forcing this script to yield to more important ones).  Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: @tadman I'm and the other devs are aware of that, and they've already added the task to their roadmap.  Like I said, it's a big undertaking and can't be done in one sitting.  It needs adequate testing in-between each table upgrade (in case, for example, any scripts rely on `MyISAM`-exclusive features).  My current task and goal is to make sure the filter continues working in the current environment (without causing another outage) until they've finished upgrading everything to `InnoDB` (which may take months or more).  Also, no miracles here - database has already tanked several times.  :P

Comment: I think the only solutions here are to either upgrade your hardware in-place, like get the fastest NVMe solution you can muster, or make a clone and do your queries off of that data-warehouse style. No easy fixes.